# I am trying to upload the image in a directory using php

Tags: php

```
//Add this product into database now

$sql = "INSERT INTO products
                (product_name,price,details,category,
                 subcategory,date_added) 
        VALUES ('$product_name','$price','$details','$category',
                '$subcategory',now())";
        //now() will add todays date in database

if($result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
    $pid = mysqli_insert_id($conn);//Generated an auto-generated id

    //Place image in the folder

    $newname = "$pid.jpg";
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileField']['temp_name'],"../inventory_images/$newname");//$_FILES is a global variable.
    header("location: inventory_list.php");//if you will not include this line then it will add the same product again if you refresh the page.
    exit();
}
else{
    echo"Data didn't inserted in the database";
}
```

Whenever I run the code it works fine, the data gets inserted and but when I check the directory for the image which I uploaded, there is nothing in that folder. Please help me as early as possible.

Comment: Is error reporting turned on?

Comment: Make sure the directory is writable.  Chmod

Comment: Double-check also that you are attempting to upload to the correct folder. Relative paths, especially with `../`, always make me nervous :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is you are using a non existing occurance in the $_FILES array in the `move_uploaded_file()` function

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileField']['temp_name'],"../inventory_images/$newname");
// - - - - - - - - - - - - -- - - - - - -^^^^^^^^^
```

Should be

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'],"../inventory_images/$newname");
```

> References
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

This really should have been generating an error. While testing you should always turn on error reporting, manually if you are testing on a live server.

> Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
>   generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: Nice catch, it's amazing how useful error reporting would have been for this person; and for 99% of the PHP-tagged questions on this site for that matter...

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Yea, I just added a suggestion about that